# How to remove frame seam of tcolorbox tcbsidebyside with frame hidden?

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to create a box with 2 tikzpictures inside. One tikzpicture should have a darker background than the other one. I first tried to use `\tcolorbox` command but I also wanted to let the lower part extend its width. So I switched over to the `\tcbsidebyside` command. Which allowed me to use the `sidebyside adapt=left` command.

Now the problem is that I also would like to have a hidden frame but it is still slightly noticable. Because I would like to use 2 colors I also did not use the enhanced jigsaw skin. Which is good for removing those `frame hidden` artefacts I have read.

So here is a simple example:

In the first two examples I show that `tcolorbox` also has this issue. It seams like its only occurs when using `sidebyside` probably because the upper part gets completely drawn and on top of that the lower part idk.
And in the last example (3) I am using the `tcbsidebyside` command which I am using currently. As seen in the picture the seam is also visible.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,skins}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    bicolor,
    frame hidden,
    colback=blue!40,
    colbacklower=blue!1,
    boxrule=0pt,
    sidebyside,
]%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (b) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    bicolor,
    frame hidden,
    colback=blue!40,
    colbacklower=blue!1,
    boxrule=0pt,
    sidebyside adapt=left,
]%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (b) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tcbsidebyside[
    bicolor,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=blue!40,
    colbacklower=blue!1,
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    frame hidden
]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (b) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example Output]

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour, `frame hidden` works for bicolor boxes but not with `sidebyside` option. Although the bad effect is not so bad when a darker color is used to fill tcblower part.

Comment: The bug has been reported: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/138 Now we need to wait for the next update.

Comment: Alight, thanks for taking care.

Comment: Fixed with version 4.50 (2021/05/21) of `tcolorbox` (may take some time to be available at CTAN; uploaded just now).